# Signification de « les chiffres sont têtus »

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Quelqu'un pourrait m'expliquer la signification des deux expressions suivantes :

> les chiffres sont têtus

et

> les faits sont têtus

Comment: Même si je peux facilement imaginer plusieurs contextes dans lesquels on emploierait ces formules, je pense que rajouter un peu de contexte dans votre question permettrait de contextualiser les réponses également, les rendant ainsi meilleures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employé dans le cas du comportement d'une personne « têtu » signifie qu'il s'agit d'une personne à qui on ne fait pas facilement changer d'avis ou qui ne fait pas d'effort pour se mettre dans la tête la vérité indiquant que ce qu'ils croient ne convient pas.
Appliqué de la présente façon à des choses comme les nombres et les faits (les nombres sont têtus), ces mots étant alors utilisés figurativement pour nommer les réalités de l'existence, cela signifie tout simplement que l'on ne peut pas aller facilement contre les vérités que la force des nombres et des faits démontrent, que l'on ne peut  inverser les conclusions qu'ils mettent en évidence que difficilement. En quelque sorte les nombres et les faits, comme les personne têtues, offrent beaucoup de résistance au changement d'un état de chose établi.

Comment: Merci pour vos explications.

Answer (score 3):

C'est quelque chose qu'on dit quand quelqu'un a une opinion ou une théorie qui est incompatible avec les faits. Que la réalité ne corresponde pas à ce qu'on attend ou à ce qui serait pratique idéologiquement ne change pas les faits : ils sont 'têtus'. "Les chiffres sont têtus" correspond au cas d'une réalité qui prend la forme d'un nombre.

Comment: Merci pour vos explications.

Comment: Ceci est une fausse explication du mot « têtu ». Quand quelqu'un a une opinion ou une théorie qui est incompatible avec les faits on dit tout simplement qu'ils ne comprennent pas ou qu'ils ont une théorie qui est fausse ; on attend pour dire qu'ils sont têtus de se rendre compte qu'il sont dans l'impossibilité, après plusieurs essais pour comprendre leur erreur, de voir les évidences qui prouvent cette théorie fausse et on dit cela seulement si la théorie est assez simple (une poignée de mathématiciens comprennent le théorème de Wiles (Fermat), mais on n'appelle pas les autres des têtus).